# How to Parse the string after reading it from a text file

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

Let say i have a text file which contain " 1 Book price $12.00" . I want to read this sting from a
and set my local variable like  int quantity , string product_type , Double price etc.
After reading the file, my  variable values should be

```
quantity  = 1;
product_type  = Book;
price = 12.00;
```

Can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: You can use Split() function to get string[], then parse the values to int (first index - quantity) and double (last index - price). But better solution would be using an Xml file for this structured data. Regards,

Comment: Also you can use RegEx to parse your text file, but XML file is still a better solution.

Comment: If you are creating this file then store it as structured XML file which is easy to maintain the code going forward.. If you are getting this file from external system where you don't have any control of formatting, use split () and your code is defensive enough to handle the null, empty string etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you would be compelled to use a text file to store data? XML would be much better and easier way to store and parse this kind of data.

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Price>12</Price>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

There are plenty of options to parse this. You can use XMLDocument, XMLReader, XElement etc you load this file and parse individual elements. Index based string manipulates tend to get ugly and error prone if you add more complex data in your text file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use XML, or you could look up JSON  [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

The syntax is really easy, and its even more lightweight than XML.

You can read this directly into Class Objects.

An Example of what the JSON would look like :-

```
[
    {
        "Qty": 1,
        "ProductType": "Book",
        "Price": 12.01
    },
    {
        "Qty": 1,
        "ProductType": "Pen",
        "Price": 12.01
    }
]
```

Here's a Code Snippet. You will need to add a reference to Newtonsoft JSON.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JSONExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadJson();
        }

        public static void LoadJson()
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Derek\Desktop\JSON.txt"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                List<Product> dataFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json);

                foreach (var product in dataFile.ToArray())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} - Price: {1} - Quantity: {2}", product.ProductType, product.Price,
                        product.Qty);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }



    public class Product
    {
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public string ProductType { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 string str = "1 Book price $12.00";
 string[] strArray = str.Split(' ');
 int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[0]);
 string product_type = strArray[1];
 decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(strArray[3].Replace("$", ""));
```